# Porque o prompt é executado de qualquer forma no javascript?

Tags: javascript

Tenho o seguinte código bem simples

```
var name = window.prompt("Digite seu nome:");
```

O metódo window.prompt está dentro de uma variavel, por que ele é executado se ele está dentro de uma variavel, eu não coloquei ele fora de uma variavel para ele poder ser executado??

Comment: Alguma resposta ajudou a resolver o problema e pode sanar dúvidas similares de outros usuários? Caso positivo não esqueça de marcar a resposta como aceita. Pra fazer isso é só clicar no ✓ do lado esquerdo da mesma (abaixo do indicador de up e down votes).

Answer (score 3):

> "*- O metódo window.prompt está dentro de uma variavel*"

Essa afirmação está errada! O certo é: a variável `name` **recebe o retorno** do método `prompt`.

Isso quer dizer que você pode receber e/ou tratar o valor (a entrada) digitada pelo usuário posteriormente:

```
var name = window.prompt('Digite seu nome');
alert('O seu nome é '+name);
```

Você pode chamar o método sem que uma variável receba o seu valor. Mas existem casos específicos para isso. Senão o usuário vai fazer uma entrada em vão!

Veja um exemplo **sem que a variável receba (armazene) o retorno**:

```
if (window.prompt('Digite "SIM" para chamar a função foo') == 'SIM') {
    foo();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> [`Window.prompt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/window/prompt)
>
> O Window.prompt() exibe uma caixa de diálogo com uma mensagem opcional solicitando ao usuário a entrada de algum texto.
>
> **Sintaxe**
>
> ```
> resultado = window.prompt(texto, valor);
> ```
>
> - `resultado` é uma cadeia de caracteres contendo o texto digitado pelo usuário, ou um valor nulo.
> - `texto` é uma cadeia de caracteres para exibir ao usuário. Este parâmetro é opcional e pode ser omitido se não há nada para mostrar na janela de prompt.
> - `valor` é uma cadeia de caracteres contendo o valor padrão exibido na caixa de entrada de texto. É um parâmetro opcional. Note que no Internet Explorer 7 e 8, se você não fornecer este parâmetro, a cadeia de caracteres "undefined" é o valor padrão.

Ou seja, você está executando a função `window.prompt` passando o parâmetro "Digite seu nome:" e está armazenando na variável apenas o retorno da função (que para este caso é o que o usuário digitar na caixa).

Para armazenar a função com o parâmetro enviado você deve realizar da seguinte forma:

```
var nome = function() { return window.prompt("Digite seu nome:"); };
```

E a execução se daria por:

```
nome();
```

```js
var nome = function() { return window.prompt("Digite seu nome:"); };
console.log(nome());
```